# Qual a melhor maneira de selecionar uma option pelo texto e não pelo valor em jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um select e gostaria de selecionar um valor de acordo com o texto de outro campo que o usuário clicou.

Por exemplo. Ao clicar numa tag "p" com o texto "Abril" eu quero selecionar o option de texto "Abril" no meu select:

```
<select id="meses">
    <option value="0">Janeiro</option>
    <option value="1">Fevereiro</option>
    <option value="2">Março</option>
    <option value="3">Abril</option>
</select>
```

Minha tag p:

```
<p class="nomMes">Abril</p>
```

Queria algo assim:

```
var valMes = $('p.nomMes').text().trim();

$(document).on('click', 'p.nomMes', function(){
    $('#meses option[text='+valMes+']).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Mas o option[text=] não funciona então qual seria a forma mais elegante de fazer isso, sem precisar dar um loop no select por exemplo?

Comment: João, sei que sua pergunta foi sobre como fazer a busca no texto, mas se formos avaliar a performance não seria melhor atribuir por exemplo o id na tag `<p>` e buscar o valor onde o id for igual?

Comment: Sim, mas é uma implementação de urgência e devido as condições que existem na geração do código pelo servidor eu teria que mudar em vários lugares e no js somente em um.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neste caso eu usaria o recurso de *[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)* do **jQuery** que vai retornar o primeiro resultado que ele encontrar com as definições da função que você determinou.

Exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Armazena nome do mês que quer selecionar
    var mes = $('.nomMes').text().trim();
    // Guarda em opt o elemento que retornar do filtro que vai testar entre as
    // options possíveis
    var opt = $('#meses option').filter(function() {
        // testa entre as options qual delas tem o mesmo conteúdo que o desejado
        return $(this).text().trim() === mes;
    });

    // Redefine o atributo do elemento encontrado pra selecionado.
    opt.attr('selected', true);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MfB7G/)**

Comment: O que seria o "el" ?

Comment: Foi sem querer hehe, força do habito de não usar jQuery, mas no jQuery ali estava vindo o "index" da iteração. Se fosse um filter do `Array.prototype.filter` o primeiro é o conteúdo da iteração, segundo é o index e terceiro a própria array. Já no jQuery eles passam o conteúdo como contexto da função de callback.

Comment: Funcionou redondinho. Obrigado!

Comment: Um prazer amigo :)

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o seletor `contains` do jQuery... não é exatamente o pedido mas resolve o problema no caso do domínio da busca possuir somente textos distintos:

```
$("#meses option:contains('"+valMes+"')").prop('selected', true);
```

### [Exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PjEgX/)

Comment: Essa solução fica bem legal também. Vou utiliza-la das proximas vezes.

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia atribuir o `value` ou `text` igual ao texto na `option`, assim:

```
<option value="Janeiro"> Janeiro </option>
```

ou

```
<option value="0" text="Janeiro"> Janeiro </option>
```

Ai precisa não utilizar o `contains`.

```
$("#meses option[value="Janeiro"]').prop('selected', true);
```

ou

```
$("#meses option[text="Janeiro"]').prop('selected', true);
```

[Realizei alguns testes](http://jsperf.com/teste-select-contais) e dessa maneira, sem `contains`, o resultado chega a ser até 80% mais rápido.